# getting AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'commit_select' after inject database in a Flask-Admin Peewee web app

Tags: python, flask, peewee, flask-admin, python-inject

Following [this example](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/examples/peewee/app.py) I integrated Flask admin with some already created peewee models. Everything looks great until I try the list view of the admin interface, but first some context:

### The Code

The important part of the **app.py** file:

```
def create_app(config_object=DevConfig):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_object)
    register_extensions(app)
    register_blueprints(app)
    register_errorhandlers(app)
    return app


def register_extensions(app):
    """Register Flask extensions."""
    assets.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    cache.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    debug_toolbar.init_app(app)
    admin = Admin(app, name=__name__, template_mode='bootstrap3')
    __add_admin_views(admin)
    return None


def __add_admin_views(admin):
    admin.add_view(ClientAdmin(entities.Client))
    return None
```

The injection of the database object in the package initialization file:

```
def persistence_config(binder):
  db_user = "postgres"
  db_name = "MY_DB_NAME"
  db_password = "MY_PASS"
  db_host = "127.0.0.1"
  db_port = 5432
  db = PooledPostgresqlExtDatabase(
    database=db_name,
    user=db_user,
    host=db_host,
    password=db_password,
    max_connections=8,
    stale_timeout=300,
    register_hstore=False)
  binder.bind(Database, lambda: db)
```

### The Error

This happens when I try to request the list of clients (http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin/client/):

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MY_ENV_PATH/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "MY_ENV_PATH/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "MY_ENV_PATH/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "MY_ENV_PATH/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "MY_ENV_PATH/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "MY_ENV_PATH/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "MY_ENV_PATH/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "MY_ENV_PATH/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "MY_ENV_PATH/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 68, in inner
    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "MY_ENV_PATH/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 367, in _run_view
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "MY_ENV_PATH/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 1738, in index_view
    view_args.search, view_args.filters)
  File "MY_ENV_PATH/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/peewee/view.py", line 353, in get_list
    query = self.get_query()
  File "MY_ENV_PATH/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/peewee/view.py", line 328, in get_query
    return self.model.select()
  File "MY_ENV_PATH/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 4458, in select
    query = SelectQuery(cls, *selection)
  File "MY_ENV_PATH/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2696, in __init__
    self.require_commit = self.database.commit_select
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'commit_select'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in my code and it was related to the way i am injecting the Database object into models. I had to use the constructor binding instead of the normal bind as i was binding a lambda function:

`binder.bind_to_constructor(Database, lambda: db)`